# Using VSTACK need to generate an indicator based on which array the values have been picked up from

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365

Given two tables of the following format containing IDs (ID1 and ID2)

[image]

[image]

I want to use VSTACK to stack the IDs on top of each other as follows:

[image]

However, I also want a second "Source" column which identifies which table I picked up the values from. Is there a clean way of doing this with dynamic formulas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are quite some ways to work on this, but in terms of readability maybe use `EXPAND()`:

[image]

Formula in `E1`:

```
=VSTACK(EXPAND(A2:A5,,2,A1),EXPAND(C2:C5,,2,C1))
```

Other option(s) could be:

```
=VSTACK(IF({1,0},A2:A5,A1),IF({1,0},C2:C5,C1))
```

Or, if you open the python interpreter through `=PY` then you can try:

```
pd.concat([xl("A2:A5").assign(a=xl("A1")),xl("C2:C5").assign(a=xl("C1"))]).values
```

Which is more tedious, and probably "bad" python, but I just wanted to give it a shot.

Comment: Nice. Finally, I see `EXPAND` in 'real' action. `=EXPAND(data,,2,header)` might be worth memorizing. The `IF` solution is also quite elegant. Well done!